# Find general location of point given conditions on its co-ordinates

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm sorry to sound like a dummy, but I've had trouble with Algebra all my life. I'm studying online with Khan Academy and one of the questions is:

Point $E$'s $y$-coordinate is $0$, but its $x$-coordinate is not $0$.
Where could point $E$ be located on the coordinate plane?

There is not graph or nothing, just a multiple choice of

- Quadrant $I$
- Quadrant $II$
- Quadrant $III$
- Quadrant $IV$
- $x$-axis
- $y$-axis

What does the $E$ mean? I understand plotting numbers and points, etc, but what is $E$?

Comment: $ E$ is a point in the plane. If you don't like the name $ E $, they could have named it "Bob" instead. It just needs a name so we can talk about it. We don't know the location of $ E $, but we are given a clue: the $ y $-coordinate of $ E $ is $0$, and its $ x $-coordinate is not $0$. Given this clue, is it possible that $ E$ is on the $ y $-axis?

Answer (score 1):

If the point $E$ has a $y$-coordinate of $0$, then it lies on the $x$-axis. Can you plot the point $(5,0)$, $(100,0)$, $(-23, 0)$. Notice what they all have in common? They lie on the $x$-axis and have a $y$-coordinate of $0$.

The equation of the $x$-axis is $y=0$. This is why, when you want to find $x$-intercepts of a function $f(x)$. You set $f(x) = 0$ to find the $x$-intercepts.

Answer (score 0):

Each point is represented by its coordinates on the plane. So your point $E$ can be represented by coordinates $$(x, y)$$

You are already told that the $y$-coordinate is 0, so the point $E$ has the form $$(x, 0)$$

Since no information is given for $x$ (ie, no restrictions for $x$), plug in some values for $x$ and draw the points on the plane. Consider $x = 3$ so plot the point $(3, 0)$. Or consider $x = -5$, and plot $(5, 0)$. It turns out that all possible points, no matter which value of $x$ you pick, will lie on the $x$-axis.

Also, an additional note: Here  $x$ was free to be whatever value you want (and thus covers the entire x-axis) but some questions may even restrict what $x$ could be. A simple example would be the above + the additional restriction that $x > 0$. Plot a few points using this, and see what you get.